# iOS App is getting slower after dismissing ModalViewController

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, modalviewcontroller

I'm developing an iOS App which has to do much work on a Modal VC. (Images, etc).

This leads to a lot of allocated Memory. Which is okay while presenting the view. 
But after dismissing the View I'm still having that Memory allocated. 
In the simulator I can free some Memory by sending a memory warning.

The problem is that my App runs slower after dismissing the view. 
I'm doing some fade and move animations after that and it is significantly slower than before.

I'm using ARC and developing for iOS 6/7. 
Do you have any ideas how to free the memory programmatically?

Comment: There is no possible way to know, without you showing the relevant code that you think is causing a problem.

Comment: Everybody could try this on his own.

Just call [self presentViewController: vc completion: nil]; 
and then dismiss it with [self dismissViewController completion:nil]; 

You will always have more memory allocated than before. 

I think showing my code will not help in this situation

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem...

I had still a reference to the Modal View in my View Controller which presented the Modal View.

But I still have the same Problem. My App runs slower after presenting the Moadl View. 
Although I don't have much memory allocated.